# match php classes in a script and create separate files for each class found

Tags: regex, parsing, class, match

My problem is with the regex to match classes and skip content that is within quotes. I also don't know how to skip the '}'s that are used to close methods inside the class, so the engine thinks that it is reaching the end of the class.

Later then I want to create separate files for each class matched. For example:

```
{$classname}.php >> content
```

This is needed because I have the terrible practice of start coding many classes in one file and then only when I've got something "meaty" then I decide to put them in separate files, which of course is too boring and spend a lot of my time. Could you help me with this please? Specially the regex, but feel free do the rest ;)

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not designed to parse programming languages (specifically nesting). Get an IDE that has refactoring tools if you want help moving code around.